# How to allow the user to choose HTML to be sent as an E-mail in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Now I'm working in a project that going to allow the user to send HTML files an E-mails . The problem here is : I made a script that going to allow him to send the HTML files as an E-mail but the HTML file must be wirtten inside the code it self , here is the question : How can I let him to chose pre-made HTML to be sent instead of integrating it into the code , and here is my current code

```
import smtplib

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# me == my email address
# you == recipient's email address
me = "Sender mail"
you = "reciver mail"

# Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "HR report"
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

# Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).
text = "Hi!\nHow are you?\nHere is the link you wanted:\nhttp://www.python.org"
html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>Hi!<br>
       How are you?<br>
       Here is the <a href="http://www.python.org">link</a> you wanted.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
"""

# Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html.
part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

# Attach parts into message container.
# According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this case
# the HTML message, is best and preferred.
msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)
# Send the message via local SMTP server.
mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

mail.ehlo()

mail.starttls()

mail.login(me, 'the Password ')
mail.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
mail.quit()
```

Comment: Create a html file that has the conte, then you include it in the email body

Comment: @DezzH This code will be converted into GUI app later so I need the user to choose the file from his device then this file added automatically